# shell request failed on channel 0

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

im using ssh to connect my university server

```
 ssh <myusername>@<server_Address>
```

after I enter my password I get this Error:

```
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
```

and the second time I tried to log in I got this message:

```
C:\Users\djamj002> ssh djamj002@hammer.cs.ucr.edu
djamj002@hammer.cs.ucr.edu's password: 
shell request failed on channel 0
```

any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specific errors that you're getting indicate that the remote server can't start a shell process to handle your login session. It appears the server that you're trying to connect to is malfunctioning, possibly due to some kind of resource shortage. You should notify the administrators of the host so that they can fix it.